# conflict between Azure.Fluent.Management and Azure.Storage.Blobs packages?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-fluent-api

In my project I had installed the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` package (version 1.27) to do resource management for my azure subscription. My connection object looks like this:

```
AzureCredentials credentials = GenerateCredentials(); // custom method that returns my creds.
IAzure azureConn = Azure
   .Configure()
   .Authenticate(credentials)
   .WithDefaultSubscription();
```

This worked fine. Today, I installed `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package with `Nuget` (version 12.4). After installing this package, I got an error:

```
> CS0234 C# The type or namespace name 'Configure' does not exist in the
> namespace 'Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

When I uninstall the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package, the error disappears. What might be going on here? I am using it in a Net Core 2.2 MVC project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the full-qualified class name instead of `Azure` class to solve the confilict, the code below is ok:

```
IAzure azureConn = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                  .Configure()
                  .Authenticate(credentials)
                  .WithDefaultSubscription();
```

The reason is that after installed `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, there is a namespace `Azure` included for blob storage. So in the code, when you type `Azure.Configure()`, the compliler will confuse, the `Azure` is `namespace` or `class`? Apprantely, it will consider `Azure` as a namespace(here, the `Azure` namespace is for blob storage), but the `Configure()` method does not in this namespce, then it will throw such error.

Comment: thank you, that was indeed the problem. Just a follow up question: Is this a design glitch, or something that cannot be avoided? It seemed weird to me since they are both Microsoft libraries, and Visual Studio didn't suggest a solution for it.

Comment: @CMorgan, I don't know if it's a design glitch. I think the vs will always use namespace over a class if they have the same name.